# SSRS Report Print readiness

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services

I have created a report in SSRS and exported to SSRS.
Requirement:
When I do a print it has to fit horiontally in one page. However because of the size of my report it gets cut.
I have figured a way to customize it in my SSRS design, however this is what i am looking for.

In excel - go to print - page set up - fit to 1:(blank)

Is there a way to achieve this in excel while exporting the report to excel?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want it to fit to 1 page for printing then I would suggest exporting it to pdf and adjusting the margins until it fits onto 1 page.

Comment: Point taken. But the requirement is an excel :(

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust DocumentHeight and DocumentWidth according to your needs